Pycharm pip install
Hello im trying to make a dicrod bot using pycharm but i try to just pip install discord im just hit with this error massage: pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

pip install

  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException




and don't know how to fix it since im new to python
Im using python 3.12 and pip 23.2.1
I tried to google to find out how to fix it

To fix "pip not recognized" in PyCharm:

Ensure Python is in system PATH
Use PyCharm's built-in package manager:

File > Settings > Project > Python Interpreter
Click "+" to add packages


Try python -m pip install discord in terminal
Restart PyCharm and/or your computer

If issues persist, check Python installation and PATH variables.

Tried that and got hit with this Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

Fix Python/pip:

Reinstall Python, add to PATH
Disable Store aliases
Restart PC and PyCharm
Try python -m pip install discord
Use PyCharm's package manager if needed


Thank you it worked after i disabled Store aliases

Could you please accept my answer so the issue closes?
